# Tensorflow not found in python 3.7.8 venv

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow inside a Python Venv and everything is working. I am using visual studio code to run my script, and when I activate the Venv and run the file with a tensorflow import, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'`. When I run `pip list` tensorflow appears and everything is downloaded. The strangest part is that when I type `python3` in the terminal and start a shell within the Venv, I can import tensorflow with no issues.

I have restarted VS code several times, and am wondering what could be causing the issue. Could it be a problem with my version of python (3.7.8)?

Comment: in vscode do you have the proper python environment selected?

Comment: I do have the correct environment selected, but it should not matter either way because I am using a venv in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with virtual environment. As I can recall, the solution was to add the correct python.exe path to .vscode/settings.json file:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "c:\\<path to your environment folder>\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```